# Возможно ли управление android-смартфонами с помощью ansible?

Tags: android, ansible

Настроил ansible для управления домашними компьютерами и VM. Можно ли использовать его и для android телефонов? (устанавливать, обновлять, удалять программы)

Comment: Если воткнёшь на ведро `ssh-server` и `python2`, то наверное что-то с `shell:` можно будет намутить.

Comment: Допустим я это сделаю, а какими командами управлять телефоном?

Comment: Там должно быть что-то типа бизибокса. Но учитывая, что ведро != классический линукс, то скорее всего тебя ждёт разочарование. Я в своё время тоже загонялся немного с этим вопросом. Глухо. Но если что получится - обязательно напиши, тоже попробую.

Comment: Пользовался раньше как SSH сервером на  Android https://arachnoid.com/android/SSHelper/index.html